# Is it possible to limit clipboard access on a per application basis in windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, clipboard

Hopefully this one is easy enough to understand, but is it possible to limit clipboard access on a per application basis, specifically in Windows 7, but I'd assume it would apply to most other versions of windows as well.

Basically, if I were to copy something to the clipboard, it seems that nearly every running application has access to that information.  Most don't seem actually do anything with it unless you push ctrl+v or click something.  However, I've noticed some applications being able to automatically fill in information with data from my clipboard before I actually paste it.  I'm assuming that most applications would then be able to access the clipboard contents at anytime.  I've seen "monitoring" applications that log/send clipboard contents periodically so what's to stop anyone from doing the same with a popular application for data mining purposes?

Is there any way possible to prevent this or have some sort of allow/deny system on a per application level?  Essentially a "clipboard firewall".

Comment: clipboard access does not require eslated permission so outside out a sandbox there isn't a way to prevent access to it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com/), a [sandbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_%28computer_security%29)ing software, which has [this capability](http://forums.sandboxie.com/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=184).